# What is wrong in this C code to find average?

Tags: c, loops

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
double sum=0;
int ii=0;
char buf[256], token[100]; // I am making this "finite length". You need to know how long the line is that you allow...

printf("Enter the numbers to average on a single line, separated by space, then press <ENTER>\n");
gets(buf, 255, stdin);
token = strtok(buf, " ");
while(token != NULL) {
sum += atof(token);
ii++;
token = strtok("", " "); // get next number
}
printf("AVERAGE: ***** %lf\ *****", sum / (double)ii);
return 0;
}
```

It gives this error-
Line 9: stdin undeclared
& when I add stdio.h header file it gives me error-
Line 11: lvalue expected

Can anyone plz correct it?

Comment: What compiler? Linux, Win or Mac? Where is line 11?

Comment: You can't assign to an array name `token`. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: to start with why dont you include stdio.h in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`token` is an Array and Array name is a non-Modifiable lvalue.

> The following object types are lvalues, but not modifiable lvalues:
>
> ```
> An array type
> An incomplete type
> A const-qualified type
> An object is a structure or union type and one of its members has a const-qualified type
> ```

You need a pointer to char. `strtok` returns pointer to the last token found in string.

So this:

```
char buf[256], token[100];
```

Should be this:

```
char buf[256], *token;
```

Also this is incorrect:

```
gets(buf, 255, stdin);
```

It should be:

```
fgets(buf, 255, stdin);
```

Your corrected code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
double sum=0;
int ii=0;
char buf[256], *token; // I am making this "finite length". You need to know how long the line is that you allow...

printf("Enter the numbers to average on a single line, separated by space, then press <ENTER>\n");
fgets(buf, 255, stdin);
token = strtok(buf, " ");
while(token != NULL) {
sum += atof(token);
ii++;
token = strtok("", " "); // get next number
}
printf("AVERAGE: ***** %lf\ *****", sum / (double)ii);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked!! :) By the way can you please explain it?

Comment: ^The answer above is self-explanatory - ask me what you did not understand. I should not have to explain the whole thing if it was written by you.

Answer (score 2):

`token` should be a pointer and not an array

so replace

```
char token[100]
```

by

```
char *token;
```

and replace this line

```
token = strtok("", " "); // get next number
```

by

```
token = strtok(NULL, " "); // get next number
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include the header file `stdio.h`.

> when I add stdio.h header file it gives me error- Line 11: lvalue expected

`token` is non -modifiable `l-vlue`. You cannot modify it.
One possible solution is declare a pointer `token_ptr` and assign the return value of `strtok`.

```
char buf[256], token[100]; // I am making this "finite length". You need to know how       long the line is that you allow...
char *token_ptr ;
printf("Enter the numbers to average on a single line, separated by space, then press  <ENTER>\n");
gets(buf, 255, stdin);
token_ptr = strtok(buf, " ");
 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

`token` is the array name which can not be assigned to . YOu need a `char *p_token` to replace it.

Comment: could u plz tell the correct line?

Comment: change line 11 which assigns the return value of strtok to token.